# Will deploying MABS on Azure to back up on-prem go via Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-backup

I would like to back up some on-prem system (SRV1) using Microsoft Azure Backup Server (MABS1), but I would like to host the MABS1
server itself on Azure as a VM and use an on-premises storage for cache/scratch (NAS1).  I want to backup for Bare Metal Recovery (BMR) and that requires a MABS.

Will the traffic flow like this:

(A) SRV1->NAS1->MABS1->Site recovery Vault?
Or
(B)
SRV1->MABS1->NAS1->MABS1->Site Recovery Vault?